# Demonstration exercise: Eigenvalues of the product of two matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm a newbie in Linear Algebra and just came across this exercise. It's a demonstration.

"Let A be a positive semidefinite matrix of "n" dimension, different from the nule matrix. Also let $\theta$ be an scalar, such that $\theta$ > 0

Let B be **B = A(A + $\theta$I$_n$)**$^-$$^1$.

Show that the eigenvalues of matrix B are in the interval [0,1>"

I was thinking that this could be solved if eigenvectors of both matrices were the same. (Because the eigenvalues of (A + $\theta$I$_n$) would be the eigenvalues of A, let's call them $\lambda$ , plus $\theta$, and therefore the eigenvalues of (A + $\theta$I$_n$)$^-$$^1$ would be 1/($\lambda$+ $\theta$). Hence the eigenvalues of B would be $\lambda$/($\lambda$+$\theta$) which are in the interval)

However, i'm not sure if this is the right path, (because i do not know how to prove that A and (A + $\theta$I$_n$)$^-$$^1$ have the same eigenvectors). So I would appreciate it if any of you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance and sorry if there are some grammatical mistakes, my native language is not english

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvectors of $(A + \theta I)^{-1}$ and of $B$ are indeed the same as the eigenvectors of $A$.  In fact, if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for eigenvalue $\lambda$, so $A v = \lambda v$, then $$(A + \theta I) v = A v + \theta v = (\lambda + \theta) v$$  Now $\lambda + \theta$ had better not be $0$, otherwise $A + \theta I$ would not have an inverse.  So we get

$$ v = (A + \theta I)^{-1} (A + \theta I) v = (A + \theta I)^{-1} (\lambda + \theta) v = (\lambda + \theta) (A + \theta I)^{-1} v$$
i.e. 
$$ (A + \theta I)^{-1} v = (\lambda + \theta)^{-1} v $$

And then $$B v = A (A + \theta I)^{-1} v = (\lambda + \theta)^{-1} B v = 
\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \theta} v$$

We can also go in the opposite direction: if $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ then it is also an eigenvector of $A$.  In fact, once you establish that $A = \theta B (I - B)^{-1}$ the proof is essentially the same.